# How to embed a Word Processor in a React webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications, embed

I need to embed a word processor with full `.docx` capabilities (mainly multi page functionality), so a rich text editor like Draft.js won't work for me.

I tried to embed a Google Docs editor in directly, and it would have been enough, but it brought along Google sign in issues. It would have been viable for users to login to their Google accounts to edit these documents (as the documents can be stored on their respective Drives using the API) but `iframe` doesn't detect cookies.

`<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/document/d/[some document ID]/edit?embed=true'>`

The closest solution what I want is [WebODF](https://webodf.org). The [demo here](https://webodf.org/demo/ci/wodotexteditor-0.5.9/localeditor.html) is basically what I need.
However this project was last updated in 2015 and there is no support anymore, so I am pretty reluctant to try this out.

Is there any tool/package/API I could use to integrate/embed a word processor in my webapp?

The app would primarily be used on the desktop with Electron, so access to the local disk isn't an issue.

Would it be more viable to configure existing tools like Draft.js to use pagebreaks?